# I need a shorter version of the following sentence: "It's no problem if you have no skill"

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to write it as a title and that's why I need a shorter version of that.

Does "**no skill, no problem**" have the same meaning?

Comment: It is hard to know what the phrase means as people without skills generally face a serious problem - how to earn a living. That's unless they have other sources of income. If you mean that only brute physical strength is required, or applicants can learn on the job, it could be better phrased.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest version I can think of is

> No skill necessary

Which is very similar to the more common

> No previous experience required.